# Blazor Enum range, CS1729 'RangeAttribute' does not contain a constructor that takes 4 arguments

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-5

I was rewriting a code snippet from BlazorApp to BlazorApp Core based application. Suddenly now it throws an error on defining RangeAttribute.

Why am I getting the error:

"CS1729 'RangeAttribute' does not contain a constructor that takes 4 arguments  TradeNow.Client"

My code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TradeNow.Client.Pages.Adverts.Data
{
    public class SellBuy
    {
            [Required]
            [Range(typeof(SellBuyN), nameof(SellBuyN.Sell), typeof(SellBuyN), nameof(SellBuyN.Buy), ErrorMessage = "Select if you are buying or selling")]
            public SellBuyN SellBuyN { get; set; }
    }
    public enum SellBuyN { Sell, Unknown, net, smth, Buy }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem .Net 5 ever admitted 4 parameters in [this constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute.-ctor?view=net-5.0). Have you recently upgraded from a different version?

Comment: @derloopkat I was using preview before, also if I put one parameter, then error is same just states 1 argument..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute?view=net-5.0

You can see the constructor never take 4 arguments:

```
Constructors
CONSTRUCTORS
RangeAttribute(Double, Double)  
Initializes a new instance of the RangeAttribute class by using the specified minimum and maximum values.

RangeAttribute(Int32, Int32)    
Initializes a new instance of the RangeAttribute class by using the specified minimum and maximum values.

RangeAttribute(Type, String, String)    
Initializes a new instance of the RangeAttribute class by using the specified minimum and maximum values and the specific type.
```